# Python while loop with one condition issue

Tags: python, while-loop

I am learning Python and was doing an exercise with the while loop statement and got confuse on why it works the way it does. For an exercise, I have to code a basic guessing game where u had three trys to guess a word. I know that in order to run the while loop statement, the condition has to be true. When I did the exercise, I had one condition expression in my while loop code and when I ran it, it didn't work. it seems like it didn't understand that my variable "out_of_gussess" was now true. I originally coded this:

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != secret_word:
    if guess_count < guess_limit: 
        guess = input("Enter guess: ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
         out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses: 
    print("out of guesses, You lose!")

else: 
    print("You Win!")
```

When I ran the code, and wasn't able to guess the word within the three attempts, my whole code breaks.

If I change the code like this below:

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != secret_word and out_of_guesses != True:
     if guess_count < guess_limit: 
         guess = input("Enter guess: ")
         guess_count += 1
     else: 
         out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses: 
    print("out of guesses, You lose!")

else: 
    print("You Win!")
```

The code rans normally without breaking and gives me an output of I lose or win depending if I guessed it or not. I am trying to understand why do I need to have my variable "out_of_gusses" to be part of the while loop condition in order for my code to work?

Comment: Your code doesn't "break", it just keeps repeating an infinite loop, because it has no reason to end the while loop.

Comment: in your original code, the only condition that will cause the `while` loop to exit is if guess == secret_word.    If you replaced `out_of_guesses == True` with `break`, then that would force the loop to stop.

Comment: Note that if guess_count >= guess_limit, is not going to ask you anymore to input the guess. So you get not output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop in the first code snippet doesn't have a case that checks to see if the guess limit has been reached so when you make your third guess and it is incorrect, the `while` loop sees that your guess is incorrect and then once inside the `while` loop it sets `out_of_guesses` to `True` because `guess_count` is no longer less than `guess_limit` then repeats the loop infinitely because the guess is always wrong which never allows it to move past the `while` loop and get to tell the user whether they were right or wrong.

Your second code snippet has that condition that checks `out_of_guesses` which stops the loop after it's been set to `True`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, after reading your comment I can see why my code didn't work, I didn't know I was in an infinite loop in my first code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version your program enters into an endless loop (the program enter the else section again and again). If you want to use the first version you must exit the loop after the else.
try this:

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != secret_word:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter guess: ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True
        break

if out_of_guesses:
    print("out of guesses, You lose!")
else:
    print("You Win!")
```

Comment: thanks I didn't think of using the break statement and also that I was in an infinite loop.